# executing multiple merge neo4j query via php

Tags: neo4j

I was using the neo4j query as below till now but I am wondering if it's making neo4j out of memory as I am not committing anywhere(I guess its auto-commit) .But the query works fine only worried if neo4j will shutdown or slow down due to my query. I really appreciate any help.

sample.php

```
<?php
if (!empty($array)) {
if( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
        $array = stripslashes( $array );
    }
    $newstr = json_decode( preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $array), true );
    if(!empty($newstr)){
        $j=0;
        foreach($newstr as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
            $category_id = $item['category_id']; //etc
            $category_name = $item['category_name'];
            $category = $item['category'];

            $data2 .=' MERGE (u'.$j.':Category {name:"'.$category_name.'",id:"'.$category_id.'",category:"'.$category
                .'"}) ';
            $j=$j+1;
        }

        $data2 = array("query" =>$data2);
        $data_string = json_encode($data2);

        $ch = curl_init('http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
        );
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

    }else{
        echo "null";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [Legacy Cypher HTTP Endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-cypher.html), which automatically commits at the end of a successful query. So, there is no need to worry about losing your data.

However, the legacy endpoint is now deprecated, so you should consider changing over to the [Transactional endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html).

Also, as a suggestion, you can change this snippet:

```
' MERGE (u'.$j.':Category {name:"'
```

to:

```
' MERGE (:Category {name:"'
```

Your query never uses the `uxxx` identifiers, so there is no need to define them in the first place.

Comment: So how can I change the existing cypher http endpoint to transactional endpoint. Should I just change : 

    POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher  to 

    POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit  ???